# How to load multiple SQL query rows into a single string variable in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a table (Table1) with multiple columns and rows. Example:

```
Column1 Coulmn2 Column3
value1  value2  value3
value4  value5  value6
```

I need to load all of the values into a single SSIS string variable (Variable1) so that the contents of the variable are:

```
value1
value2
value3
------
value4
value5
value6
```

"------" indicates the next row.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Column1 + char(13) + Column2....

Answer (score 0):

Using an adaptation to a standard csv creator replacing ',' with char(13)

```
declare @t table (c1 varchar(20), c2 varchar(20), c3 varchar(20) )

insert into @t
values
('d1','d2','d3')
,('d4','d5','d6')

select stuff(( select char(13) + c1+char(13)+c2+char(13)+c3
                from @t
                for xml path(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'')
```

Use an execute SQL task and save result to your variable.

Comment: Thanks but that not what I was looking for. I need new lines after each column.

Comment: You cannot row base your variables. Why do you wanna rowbase your variable? a variable string is like "test,test,test,test,test" If you need values you need to make an object variable which you can loop over.

Comment: This does make new lines after each column, however, I'm not sure why you would do this